# Android change the include tag's layout attr dynamically

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, include

I'm using the `<include>` tag to include my layout which merged by `AppBarLayout` and `FloatingActionButton` in my MainActivity.

And the MainActivity has 5 fragments in the `NestedScrollView` with a bottombar to switch them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myCoordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    android:id="@+id/layout_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/appbar_profile" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I wished that the `<include>` tag's `layout` attribute can be reset to another layout resource(such as `setLayoutResource(R.layout.appbar_profile)`) while switching to other fragment(`profile` page).

How to change the `<include>` tag's `layout` attribute dynamically? thx.

Comment: I want this too...

Comment: did you find solution for this? i also want this